# Firebase Analytics: Parameter name selection for event is empty even though I have setup custom definition

Tags: java, android, firebase-analytics

This is how I log firebase event in my app

```
public static void trackGAEvent(String name, String screenName) {
    FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics = Utils.getFirebaseAnalytics();

    if (firebaseAnalytics == null) {
        return;
    }

    Bundle bundle = null;

    if (screenName != null) {
        bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, screenName);
    }

    firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(name, bundle);
}

trackEvent("review_ok", "screen_name_A");
trackEvent("review_ok", "screen_name_B");
```

---

By using custom definition, I expect I can break down the event `review_ok` to `screen_name_A` and `screen_name_B`.

[image]

However, when I look at the even of `review_ok`, the parameter name selection is empty.

[image]

Do you know what else I have missed out?

Comment: I have the same problem, dont know how to fix it though i can see parameters in a debug mode

Answer (score 0):

This problem cause me a big headache, but I realized that the site was not visited by enough people. After some time, as more data arrived on my page, the parameters for my event appeared.
You can read about these thresholds here: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9268042?visit_id=638190021689212752-425852670&rd=1

I hope this solves your problem too!